# looking for loop or something else ,just want to get rid of all these if, to make the code smaller

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

```
  $num = 1
 if ($unix[9] == $num) {   
 $out[0] = $letters[1];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 1) { 
 $out[1] = $letters[2];``
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 2) {
 $out[2] = $letters[3];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 3) {
 $out[3] = $letters[4];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 4) {
 $out[4] = $letters[5];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 5) {
 $out[5] = $letters[6];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 6) {
 $out[6] = $letters[7];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 7) {
 $out[7] = $letters[8];
}
 if ($unix[9] == $num + 8) {
 $out[8] = $letters[9];
}
```

I'm looking for a loop to avoid the above lines, or something else to replace most of the if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($num = 1, $max = 9 ; $num < $max ; $num++){
  if ($unix[9] == $num) {   
     $out[$num] = $letters[$num + 1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 1
for($i=1;$i<=9;i++) {
    if ($unix[9] == $num+($i-1)) {   
        $out[$i-1] = $letters[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `$num`? It never changes and you remove its value with `== $num+($i-1)`, it's equivalent to just saying `== $i`.

Comment: The only reason I kept it was because I assumed the OP might need it somewhere else. If not, then yes it could be removed as you noted.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the job

```
for ($num = 1; $num < 9; $num++) {

    if ($unix[9] == $num) {

        $out[$num - 1] = $letters[$num];
    }
}
```